# Decoding JSON APIs in Swift - Duplicate Struct Names

Tags: ios, json, swift, struct

My app parses a number of APIs in Swift some of which share similar names for dictionaries and/or arrays.

I can't control the names of the incoming JSON dictionaries arrays as they come from API endpoints. Currently I have one utility class that processes all these APIs. How can I parse APIs that share common names?

Here is what I'm using for one API.

```
 struct aVideo: Codable {
        let page, totalResults, totalPages: Int
        let results: [Result]
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case page
            case results
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Result
    struct Result: Codable {
        let popularity: Double
        let voteCount: Int
        let video: Bool
    }
```

This other API uses the same key, Result and it is throwing an error.

```
// MARK: - WordInfo
    struct WordInfo: Codable {
        let word: String
        let results: [Result]
        let frequency: Double
    }

     // MARK: - Result
    struct Result: Codable {
        let definition, partOfSpeech: String
        let synonyms, entails, hasTypes, derivation: [String]
    }
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON itself doesn't define the name of the structure -- only the name of the property that holds it, so you're safe to redefine the names of your structs as needed:

```
struct WordInfo: Codable {
        let word: String
        let results: [WordInfoResult]
        let frequency: Double
    }

     // MARK: - Result
    struct WordInfoResult: Codable {
        let definition, partOfSpeech: String
        let synonyms, entails, hasTypes, derivation: [String]
    }
```

The decoder will know that when it gets to `results` on `WordInfo` that it should be parsed as the type `[WordInfoResult]` because that's how you've defined it.